# C# Web Service to respond to XML Payload

Tags: c#, xml, payload

I trying to build a service that responds to an XML request from an application with an XML document in C#.

After creating an asmx service that took in parameters I found out that the application (which is a black box and I only now the format of the data sent and what needs to be received) is sending an XML Payload.

Google is only giving me hints and I'm not sure how I should implement the service. Does it sound like I should create a ReSTful service? Does an XML Payload get delivered as a stream rather than parameters as seems to be the case?

Comment: ASMX is now a legacy technology. It should not be used to create new applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build the solution using WCF instead; take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx) on MSDN as a starting point.